# Initialization array of structs - {NULL} vs {}

Tags: c, arrays, struct

If I have this struct:

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int type1;
    char *type2;
    char type3[CHARS_AMOUNT];
} MyStruct;
```

What would be the difference between following initialization:

option 1:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyStruct someObjects[5] = {};
}
```

option 2:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyStruct someObjects[5] = {NULL};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the first is illegal in standard C, and the second may or may not be.

`{}` in an initializer is not legal in C; you need at least one element between the `{` and `}`. (Some compilers might permit it as an extension; I think gcc does.)

A common idiom is

```
some_type blah[] = { 0 };
```

The initial element is initialized to `0` (which could be a null pointer, floating-point zero, a null character, etc.), and the remaining unspecified elements are initialized to zero for the appropriate type.

With the `{NULL}` initializer you're trying to initialize `someObjects[0].type1`, an `int` to `NULL`. The `NULL` macro is intended to be used as a null pointer constant. It *may or may not* be defined as a constant `0`, so the legality of your initializer is implementation-specific.

Just write

```
MyStruct someObjects[5] = {0};
```

Comment: Is it the same in gcc to write { 0 } and { } ?

Comment: @SuperMario: Not in all cases. Another gcc extension is that it permits empty structures. So `struct empty { } obj = { };` is valid in GNU C, but `struct empty { } obj = { 0 };` gets at least a warning. Apart from that, as far as I know, they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The first version is immediately illegal. C language does not support `{}` initializers.

The second version is generally illegal, even though it might "compile" in some implementations. In this case, in accordance with the rules of aggregate initialization your `NULL` will act as an initializer for `someObjects[0].type1` field. This field has type `int`. However, even though in many implementations you might be able to successfully initialize `int` objects with `NULL`, in general case it is not possible. `NULL` is intended to be used in pointer context, not in integer context.

If you want to zero-initialize your entire array, the proper way to do it is

```
MyStruct someObjects[5] = { 0 };
```

Answer (score 2):

`MyStruct someObjects[5] = {};` isn't conformant C and 
whether `MyStruct someObjects[5] = {NULL};` is conformant C is implementation defined*.

You should initialize it with `MyStruct someObjects[5] = {0};`. `{0}` is the way to default/zero-initialize any array, aggregate object or compound literal in C.

`{0}` works for default/zero-initialization because [6.7.9p19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19) and [6.7.9p20](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p20) will cause the `0` to recursively target the first primitive object, because every primitive data object in C is either numerical or a pointer and therefore initialiazable with `0` and finally because [6.7.9p21](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21) says that:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

---

*`NULL` could be defined as `0` in which case `{NULL}` is OK, or it could just as well be defined `(void*)0` in which case `{NULL}`'s not OK in your case because recursively, you're array's first primitive object (`int type1;`) is not a pointer initalizable from `(void*)` or even a pointer.